# Responsive Jquery function not working when window resize

Tags: jquery, responsive-design

After resizing the browser window, this function is not working on first time, but after reload the page, it works.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if($(document).width() < 620){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".flexy-menu").flexymenu({
            speed: 400,type: "vertical", indicator: false
        });
    });
}
</script>
```

Why is it working only after reload ?

Answer (score 2):

have you tried writing the function inside resize function

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $( window ).resize(function() {
          if($(document).width() < 620){            
               $(".flexy-menu").flexymenu({
                      speed: 400,type: "vertical", indicator: false
               });    
           }
        });
    });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($(document).width() < 620){            
            $(".flexy-menu").flexymenu({
                speed: 400,type: "vertical", indicator: false
            });    
    }
 });
</script>
```

Have you considered to wait first for the document to be ready? You also missed the starting  tag